# How would I go about creating levels in a game that scroll automatically?

Tags: game-engine

I'm working on a 2D shmup, and the idea is that the level continuously scrolls automatically, and your character can move around the screen.

Now, I'm having trouble figuring out how I would implement this and Google hasn't been any help.  Right now I have a scrolling background (the background position is simply decremented for each frame) and the player can move around freely in the window, but how would I go about creating the objects in the level?  Would I just use a timer to trigger objects and enemies or is there a way to do it based on the position/width of the background (I'd prefer the second method...But I have no clue how that would be done)?

Since this is a general question and doesn't really pertain to any of my code that I've already written as far as I know, I don't think I need to include any of it...But I'll be happy to provide any part of it if needed.

Comment: You may also be interested in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: note that if you do it based on position/width, depending on the game and how it's implemented, it may give an advantage to people with slower CPU (or throttled or any way to limit the CPU usage of your game).

Comment: This is a generic game concept, IMO.  The underlying programming technology doesn't have much impact on how you should solve this at a high level (C++, SDL, object).

Comment: I think it does have an impact on the programming technology since I'm trying to figure out how I would code it...And it may or may not have a solution specific to C++ or SDL, which is why I added those tags (so people would know how I can solve my problem with what I'm using).

Comment: @LieRyan Then the game engine already has *other* issues :)

Comment: This is definitely "not a real [SO] question" though. Design the game how you want it -- that's subjective, and your decision. Then, you can ask a more refined question of *how* to do it, providing code for existing attempts and what did or didn't work, which framework is being used, whatever. (But at least it would be an *objective* question.)

Comment: @pst: My suggested solution involves programming aspects: A queue, a list, rectangle intersection tests, and timers/clock values.  Compare this question to a question like "how would I go about making sure an array of integers is in ascending order?"  Though I might agree that the [gamedev.SE] site might be a better community for this particular question.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I think your answer was great. I [still] don't think this question is :-) I think the problem is that it doesn't remove the subjective elements of how the game should function and, in a strange way, seems to accent them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend either:

- Use physical triggers
- Use a list of timed events

#### Physical triggers

Simply place a box on your level.  When it scrolls partially or completely onto the screen (whichever makes more sense - maybe use both in different cases?), you trigger the event associated with that trigger.

This would be simpler to support in a level editor because the physical nature is inherently very easy to visualize.

#### Timed events

You basically create a timer object at the beginning of the level, and an ordered queue of events.  In your game update loop, peek at the head of the queue.  If the trigger time of the item at the head of the queue is less than the current elapsed time, pop the item off the queue and trigger the event.

Timed events would be more generically useful because it would also support non-scrolling level, or non-scrolling portions of levels.

#### Combination of both

You could also do some sort of combination of these to get the benefits of both styles: Easier visualization/level editing, and supporting non-scrolling sections or time-based events.

Each physical trigger will have its own script queue.  When the trigger is hit, a timer is started and an event queue is created.  That timer and queue is added to a list of currently running timers and queues.

In your update function, you check all items on the list, and trigger events the same way you did with the timed event queue above.  Once a queue is emptied, you remove it from the list of timers/queues.

#### How to detect that a trigger is on-screen

You should implement scrolling first.

One you have scrolling, calculate the rectangle that matches where the screen is located in your pixel/world coordinate system.  This will give you the "bounding box" of the screen.

From here, do an intersection test between your event trigger's "bounding box" and the screen.

Here is a test to see if there is *any* overlap between two rectangles.  It isn't order-specific:

```
rect1.left < rect2.right && rect1.right > rect2.left
    && rect1.top < rect2.bottom && rect1.bottom > rect2.top
```

If the rects are touching at all, it will return true.

Here is a test to make sure `rect1` **contains** `rect2`.  Order is important:

```
rect1.left <= rect2.left && rect1.right >= rect2.right
    && rect1.top <= rect2.top && rect1.bottom >= rect2.bottom
```

If `rect2` is completely contained by `rect1` (it is completely on-screen), it will return true.

#### How to implement simple timers

Simply get some sort of clock value (could be [`SDL_GetTicks`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetticks.html)), and store that value.

To see how long has elapsed since that timer was started, call the function again and subtract.  Compare the values with `<` to see if the difference is greater than the target time.

Comment: I'd want to use the timed events since there are portions where it'd need to stop for story elements and midboss/boss battles...How would I create the queue?

Comment: @user1122136: I would create the queue on level load/hard level restart (e.g. after death and checkpoint reset).  It would be similar to loading other content (like your level, bitmaps, animations, etc).  You could either load it from a file on disk, or manually hard-code the queue creation code into your program.  If you end up creating a custom level editor, I'd design it to output to a custom file/section of your level file.  When loading the data into the queue, simply add your event objects one item at a time.  Then you'd probably need to sort them by event time...

Comment: Ah, okay...Makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is where you should use pointers. Something along the lines of:

```
vector<BadGuy*> Listofbaddies;

//Place enemy just off screen
newYposition = SCREEN_HEIGHT + 20;

//an infinite (almost) amount of badguys can be created with this code:
Listofbaddies.push_back(new Badguy(newXposition,
                                   newYposition,
                                   EnemyType,
                                   blahblah);
```

Which means that the badguy will need a constructor like:

```
Badguy::Badguy(float newX, float newY, string Type, whateverelseyouwant){

actualSpritePartOfBadguyClass.setPosition(newX, newY);
}
```

Does that make sense? I'll elaborate if you ask :D
I'm making a game now that uses something similar :)

Comment: It makes sense to me...But why would I need to use pointers?  In the code I have to test I have a regular vector and push_back the test enemy when the player is at the center of the screen.  Also, if I do it like that, would I have to add to the enemy code to make them start acting when the player is a certain distance to them, or how would I handle that?

Comment: Because without the pointers you would have to name each badguy that comes along, or have a thousand badguys with the same name, or fight the same 1 enemy over and over :/ I'm sure it could work, but after 2 years of hating pointers, i finally gave in and started doing it this way XP

Comment: @Magicaxis: still confused, you don't need a pointer to have a thousand badguys with different names, or to not name the badguys.

Comment: I suppose it could be done without them, but this way is (according to my lecturer anyway) more memory efficient and uses less lines.